# Keycloak created user enabled

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I am using keycloak 4.8.3 Final for my project. I have been reading keycloak documentation for 6 days.
I am using keycloak  registration page. When i register, user always enabled, but in my scenario admin has to enable created user. I do not know why but i can not find it in keycloak documantation. I tried to change register flow but nothing change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that we can't change this in 4.8.3 Final version. You can change java code and rebuild it, or you can use REST API.